# VFD output connection related query

Tags: vfd

What will happen in an VFD if any two terminal of the output power given to motor (R,Y,B) are interchanged

Comment: Typically the motor runs in the opposite direction than it did before the switch.

Answer (score 2):

VFDs are used to drive three-phase motors. Swapping two phases will have the effect of reversing the phase sequence.

[image]

*Figure 1. Effect of swapping two phases.*

Answer (score 0):

Interchanging two phases in a VFD output will reverse the direction of motor rotation. This can be eithor done physically or by means of parameters in the Control unit of VFD.